# How do I change which server a Visual Studio solution opens with in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have an asp.net website solution and at some point someone altered the solution so that when running it in debug mode, it no longer uses the built in VS web server, rather it uses an IIS 7 sserver hosted on  my local machine. For testing purposes, as well as to have a better understanding of VS, I want to change it back so the website opens with the built in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you're using a Web Site Project (WSP) or a Web Application Project (WAP).  The two are implemented very differently in VS.

If you have a WAP, the settings can be configured in the project properties.  To get here, either right-click the project and select Properties, or double-click the Properties node (for VB, it's called My Project instead) under the project. Then go to the Web tab:

[image: Properties node in Solution Explorer]
[image: Server settings]

If you have a WSP, there isn't a way to convert the project to use different settings.  Instead, just do Open Website and point it at the folder where your site lives.  (Although, given that there isn't a conversion process, I doubt you have a WSP.)

Comment: I have a solution that has two projects, a web project, my main project of concern, and a library project for reports. I don't have the same properties page you show, I have a Start Actions page but I don't see anywhere that I can change the option to use IIS Express or the built in server.

Comment: @AlanFisher Hm, sounds like you may have a Web Site Project.  For those, there isn't really a way to switch the server.  Instead you need to open the Website through a different means.  The Open Website dialog, it should show options for File System and Local IIS (among others).  File System will by default use the VS development server.